# Is it possible to redirect using dropdown onchange using value as parameter?

Tags: php, redirect, yii2

Using Yii2 I have the following code which displays a dropdown with my list of categories.

I was wondering is it possible so that on change the action executed is localhost:8888/article/category?id=1 rather that what it is atm (localhost:8888/article/category).

Does this require AJAX and/or JS or can it be done just using php?(id prefer php)

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'category-form', 'action' =>   
'/advanced/article/category',]); ?>

 <?= $form->field($model, 'category')->dropDownList($model->categoryList,[

'prompt'=>'Select Category to view',
'onchange'=>'this.form.submit()'

]) ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You dont need ajax for this. js will do it.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'category')->dropDownList($model->categoryList,[
                                'prompt'=>'Select Category to view',
                                'id'=>'cat-id',
                            ]) ?>
```

And js to redirect when selected

```
$this->registerJs( 
'$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#cat-id").change(function(){
var e = document.getElementById("cai-id");
    var strSel =  e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    window.location.href="'.Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('category?id=').'" + strSel;
});

});', View::POS_READY);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want use `onchange` attribute without writing any additional javascript, you need correct your code a bit more to get it working.

**1)** Change you form [method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activeform.html#$method-detail) to `get` (by default it's `post`):

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'category-form',
    'action' => '/advanced/article/category',
    'method' => 'get', // Add this to your code
]); ?>
```

**2)** Explicitly set name of the category field in [dropDownList](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#dropDownList%28%29-detail) options to avoid wrapping in [formName()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#formName%28%29-detail):

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'category')->dropDownList($model->categoryList, [
    'prompt'=>'Select Category to view',
    'onchange'=>'this.form.submit()',
    'name' => 'category', // Add this to your code
]) ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

sorry you can make a onchange example but this time with a radiolist in yii2

field($model, 'estadoLaboral')->radioList(array('T'=>'Actualmente trabajo aquí','B'=>'Ya no trabajo aquí')) ?>
using javascript